# AXIOS request: "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80"

Tags: async-await, axios

Trying to understand what's going on with my GET request. I set this up on the backend using node.js. I first thought I was using the wrong .env, url, username, and password... but when I checked on Postman, Basic Auth seemed to be getting the JSON data without any issues. Am I using AXIOS wrong?

Here's my GET request:

```
let customers;
try {
    let user_res = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "api._____.com/customers",
        auth: {
            username: process.env.USERNAME,
            password: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
    });
    customers = user_res.data;
    console.log(customers);
} catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
        "API failed, please try again.",
        500
    );
    return next(error);
}
```

---

ERROR Log:

```
API_NAME error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 80,
    config: {
        url: 'api.___.com/customers',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.1'
        },
        auth: {
        username: '___',
        password: '___'
        },
        transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
        timeout: 0,
        adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> Writable {
        _writableState: WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        afterWriteTickInfo: null,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: false,
        errored: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
        },
        writable: true,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: {
        protocol: 'http:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        path: 'api.___.com/customers',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        agents: [Object],
        auth: '___',
        hostname: null,
        port: null,
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: 'api.___.com/customers'
        },
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 0,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
        _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object: null prototype],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        outputData: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Socket],
        _header: 'GET api.___.com/customers HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
            'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
            'User-Agent: axios/0.19.1\r\n' +
            'Host: localhost\r\n' +
            'Authorization: Basic ___==\r\n' +
            'Connection: close\r\n' +
            '\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        path: 'api.___.com/customers',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: false,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        reusedSocket: false,
        _redirectable: [Circular *1],
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
        [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
        },
        _currentUrl: 'http:api.___.com/customers',
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    response: undefined,
    isAxiosError: true,
    toJSON: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Comment: Hey, are you still having this issue?

Comment: @Abe yes I tried running "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN" on my terminal, but didn't see port 80 being used

Answer (score 16):

I understand that your url is defined like: `api.___.com/customers`, however you should define it like `http://api.___.com/customers` or `https://api.___.com/customers` if you have it.

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

try `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Using `0.0.0.0` as opposed to `localhost` worked for me in the context of Electron. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, 127.0.0.1 means that it's being refused by your local computer (127.0.0.1) on port 80. Maybe you need to add an exception to that port your local machine? Another thing to look out for is CORS issues if your server itself, but typically that is met with an error detailing that to be the case.

Comment: So I tried running "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN" on my terminal, but didn't see port 80 being used

Comment: Try this command my guy `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I have a mac so I don't think I can use iptables. Would pf work? If so, what would be the equivalent? Lastly, should I just create a separate stack question and have you answer that and then link it to this question?

Comment: It would be more clear to edit your current question for future readers!

Comment: Another note, have you tried running the script as root? Or even changing which port you're hosting the API you're trying to self reference on? So for instance, instead of 80, host the API on 8080 temporarily for testing purposes.

Edit: [This link to another article](https://serverfault.com/questions/742364/port-80-connection-refused-how-to-fix-on-mac-osx)  may help you as well in opening port  80 on Mac

Answer (score 1):

I set the URL with HTTP and the problem is solved!

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/user.json', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case i found a solution :
I deploy my API project using localhost:8000, and it sounds like localhost is not directly 127.0.0.1 because of my host.conf file.
So i deploy my lumen app on 127.0.0.1:8000 then my expressJs connection worked

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt 3 user here. For me it was because I set up sitemap creation before all plugins etc. were loaded; so axios.defaults.baseurl caused an error. I changed the variable to https://api.blahblah.com and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my company proxy was automatically refusing traffic from localhost. When I properly configured the noproxy variable in the same terminal I was running my program from, I started getting the responses from the localhost endpoints that I was expecting.