# getting photos from one endpoint and saving in another one - nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

Basically what I want to do is get photos from another endpoint in spacex API. The photos are on endpoint rockets/rocket_id, and im trying to get them but always gets an empty values.
spaceX api is someone want to see it : https://docs.spacexdata.com/

```
api = require("./api")
// ...
server.get('/rockets', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.get('/v3/launches');
        var lista = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const img = api.get('/v3/rockets/' + data[i].rocket['rocket_id']);
            lista.push({
                name_rocket: data[i].rocket['rocket_name'],
                first_stage: data[i].rocket['first_stage']['cores'][0]['core_serial'],
                second_stage: data[i].rocket['second_stage']['payloads'][0]['payload_mass_kg'],
                link_patch: data[i]['links']['mission_patch'],
                link_video: data[i]['links']['video_link'],
                details: data[i]['details'],
                launch_site: data[i]['launch_site']['site_name'],
                img: img
            });
        }
        return res.send(lista);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({ error: error.message });
    }
});

server.get('/link', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.get('/v3/rockets/falcon9');
        var lista = [];

        lista.push({
            imagem: data['flickr_images']
        });

        return res.send(lista);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({ error: error.message });
    }
});
```

api.js:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'api.spacexdata.com', });

module.exports = api;
```

Comment: Where are you defining "api"? Does that include the base of the URL?

Comment: yes. I forgot to put the code of api:
const axios = require("axios");

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.spacexdata.com/',
});

module.exports = api;

and i made a require getting the file api: 
const api = require("./api");

Comment: Can you update the original question with any errors you're getting? Also, what is response.status? Is the value of `data` "empty" (eg an empty array), or is it undefined/null?

Comment: i add the endpoint ("/link") wich is the one that i want to get the infos. There is no error, and the values are empty.

Comment: Try wrapping the call in a try/catch to check the errors:
try {
        console.log('getting the rocket')
        const result = await foo.get('/v3/rockets/falcon9')
        console.log("success", result)
} catch(err) {
        console.log("error", err)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from the URL. You need "http://" or "https://".

```
axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://api.spacexdata.com'})
```

To debug this in the future, consider a try/catch and some logging. The `console.log(err)` below gave me a much more detailed error that I was able to google.

```
try{
  const result = await api.get(...)
  console.log(result)
catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Related: [StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557433/axios-request-error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-180)

---

In case these were also causing problems, it looks like you're missing an await and some object drilling here:

```
const img = api.get('/v3/rockets/' + data[i].rocket['rocket_id']);
```

Should be changed to this:

```
const { data } = await api.get('/v3/rockets/' + data[i].rocket['rocket_id']);
const imgs = data.flickr_images
```

2. You could probably use GET `/rockets` once instead of GET `/rockets/:id` in a loop in the first endpoint for performance.
3. v3 of this API is deprecated. Would suggest moving to [v4](https://github.com/r-spacex/SpaceX-API/blob/master/docs/rockets/v4/one.md).

Comment: but if i use this const { data } in the new endpoint with the rocket id wouldn't get conflict with the { data } endpoint v3/rockets/ ?
I tried this and i get "error": "Cannot access 'data' before initialization"

Comment: Sure. Change the variable name, eg `const { data: rocketData }`. The code I provided is meant for example purposes and might need to be edited to fit your code, since I don't have all of the context :-)